# Riddle: "What will become of me?"

Tags: riddle

Taken from my mother's breast, 
I have been imprisoned in a cave.
Why did they do this, and what will become of me?

Comment: is one of the below answers correct, or on the right track?

Comment: User ran is very close. I edited the wording of the riddle slightly to make it a little more clear

Answer (score 4):

Just a random thought.

> They will eat you

Torn from my mother's breast.

> This refers to plucking a fruit from the tree. Some trees produce a white milky sap while plucking the fruit. That refers mom child breast feed relation ship.

I have been imprisoned in a cave.

> This refers to the process of riping fruits. People put fruits in a box with no sunlight or air to ripe it.

Why did they do this, and what will become of me?

> They will eat you because they are hungry.

Comment: (I don't know how to add spoilers to the comments so I can't say much)
"Why did they do this?"
You got this part right. But you're just slightly off the mark about the part that's "Torn from my mother's breast."

Comment: That was a quick thought. Waiting for the hints. :)

Comment: Maybe it la about milk fruit https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysophyllum_cainito

Answer (score 3):

> The story of the life of veal calves is who you are referring to.

Torn from my mother’s breast

> Veal calves are raised on a milk formula supplement.

I have been imprisoned in a cave

> Veal calves live the entirety of their short lives in wooden crates that severely restrict the calves' movement.

Why did they do this, and what will become of me?

> The crates mentioned above are designed to prohibit exercise and normal muscle growth in order to produce tender “gourmet” veal.  The tender veal will be eaten.

Comment: Note: I don’t know how to edit for Spoilers...

Comment: You can add spoiler tags by putting the characters >! before each line you want to hide.